# Can we guess the first 2 characters of a HMAC-SHA256 hash if we know the messages, can see all outcomes but have no idea about the key?

Tags: statistics, sha256, hmac, forecast

My question is this: You are providing a message (i.e. helloworld:0) to someone with a key, who will take HMAC-SHA256 of the message and show you the output. He will never tell you what is the key, but always use the same key and will show you every output for the message provided.

- Is there any method that you suggest to increase the probability of guessing the outcome or only the first character of the outcome correctly? Like "send 1000 messages "helloworld:1" ... "helloworld:10000" and check seasonality of the outcome"?

(This does not work. All data seems random with 0.00001 deviation from mean for 1000000 data. But maybe I should tailor the messages (but I don't know what to do)? Despite there is no claim by the authors, HMAC-SHA256 seems random)

Comment: think you might want to search for the term "chosen plaintext attack" and maybe see this https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/8087/72896.  the paper linked to in the answer talks about requirements for HMAC to be a PRF

Comment: @SamMason Thanks. What I understand is "HMAC using SHA256 is a PRF" in short. But even with a PRF, can we tailor the messages such that there will be i.e. no letter "p" in any of outputs?